# Create Popup in SuiteCommerce

Tags: netsuite

I want to create popup dialog clicking a tag.

```
<a href='mailto:test@test.com'> test@test.com </a>
```

Clicking this tag show popup dialog to send email.
It should have email address field, name field, message field and etc.

This site is built with SuiteCommerce.

Comment: So a popup would appear, including email, name and message fields. I'm assuming there'd also be a submit button too?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use a library like jQuery to easily show a normally hidden pop-up div.

Your code would be like the following and assumes you have a jQuery library loaded on the page, as well as an endpoint `/destination` to submit the form to. You'd also want to apply stying to make the pop-up centered and otherwise look ok.

```
<html>
<body>    
    <a href='mailto:test@test.com' id="email_to_click"> test@test.com </a>

    <div id="popup" style="display:none">
        <form action="/destination">
            Name: <input type="text" name="my_name"><br>
            Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
            Message <input type="text" name="message"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
    <style>
        #popup
        { 
          position:absolute;
          width:400px;
          top: 50%;
          left: 50%;
          margin-left: -200px; // 1/2 width
          margin-top: -200px; // 1/2 height }
    </style>
    <script>
        $.ready(
            $("#email_to_click").click(function(){
                $("#popup").show();})
            )
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But clicking Submit button how can I send email?

Comment: You need another mechanism to receive and then send the email.  It could be a RESTlet in Netsuite, which would receive the submitted email address and message,  then using a backend NetSuite script, would actually send the email. When you create the RESTlet, you get a url, which would be the destination for the form.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I have question.  In script am I have to use nlapiSendEmail function not am I?  If so how can I set author parameter then? It is internal id of author I think

Comment: Yes, for the back-end, NetSuite script you'd want to use `nlapiSendEmail`. As for author, I'm not sure if it's internal ID you need, or if you can just use a string like `"david@test.com"`. Try both?

Comment: the latter one I mean 'david@test.com' isn't working properly.  So you need to use internal id but visitors have no internal id

Comment: For the visitor, you can just use a string containing the email address (or multiple addresses)

Comment: Thanks for your help but I want to know in details. How could I set author parameter in nlapisendemail function? 'davidcote412@gmail.com' is not working. It is working properly when you enter internal id i.e -5, or etc.

Comment: Yes, according to the NetSuite documentation, 'author' requires an internal ID for an employee record.

Answer (score 0):

You need several components to set up in place

- A button with a link that will reveal the popup and data-toggle="display-in-modal". The link should point to a route defined to instance the view
- A router that links the route above with the view to be created
- A view containing a template with the logic and fields you want to create.

If you want an example take a look at the address_details.tpl which uses this same scheme to open an edit modal for the address.